# Delphi Port code from VCL into FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I've this BitmapDecoder module

```
function  DecryptBmp(FHandle:pointer; FBitmap,FData:pointer; DataSize:integer):boolean;cdecl; external 'BmpDecrypter.dll';
```

i've used it with VCL in this way :

```
procedure TBmpDecrypter.Decrypt(ASourceData: pointer; ASourceSize: integer);
var
  isDecrypted:boolean;
begin

    if FHandle = nil then Exit;

      isDecrypted:= DecryptBmp(FHandle, FDestBmp.ScanLine[FDestBmp.Height-1],ASourceData, ASourceSize);
      if isDecrypted then 
       ShowMessage('Bmp decrypted with success')
       else
       ShowMessage('Bmp can''t be decrypted !')

end;
```

So please how can i port this into FMX , Just this part :

```
DecryptBmp(FHandle, FDestBmp.ScanLine[FDestBmp.Height-1]{Can we use the TBitmapData here ?},ASourceData, ASourceSize);
```

many thanks

Comment: You need to first work out what your existing code actually does. What the parameters are, and so on. A signature is not enough. You should look at the calling code, and the libraries documentation.

Comment: @ David , i'm just struggling with  `FDestBmp.ScanLine[FDestBmp.Height-1]`

The Module is mine and is being used in my VCL version

Comment: Why on earth has this question been 'put on hold' *after* I've actually answered it (and the answer got accepted)? If any of you have any concrete experience in FMX, I'd be amazed, because the question was clear enough otherwise (the original FMX TBitmap actually had a ScanLine property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to 'decrypt' to a TBitmapSurface object instead of a TBitmap directly, something like this:

```
procedure TBmpDecrypter.Decrypt(ASourceData: pointer; ASourceSize: integer);
var
  isDecrypted:boolean;
  Surface: TBitmapSurface;
begin
  if FHandle = nil then Exit;
  Surface := TBitmapSurface.Create;
  try
    Surface.SetSize(FDestBmp.Width, FDestBmp.Height); //!!! see note below
    isDecrypted := DecryptBmp(FHandle, Surface.ScanLine[Surface.Height - 1], ASourceData, ASourceSize);
    FDestBmp.Assign(Surface);
    if isDecrypted then 
      ShowMessage('Bmp decrypted with success')
    else
      ShowMessage('Bmp can''t be decrypted !')
  finally
    Surface.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This assumes the second parameter to the DLL function is only for output. If it is for input too, then you need to do this instead of the SetSize line:

```
Surface.Assign(FDestBmp);
```

Another, unconnected point of style: you shouldn't be calling ShowMessage directly on an error, but raising an exception:

```
type
  EDecryptBmpError = class(Exception);

//...

implementation

procedure TBmpDecrypter.Decrypt(ASourceData: pointer; ASourceSize: integer);
var
  Surface: TBitmapSurface;
begin
  if FHandle = nil then Exit;
  Surface := TBitmapSurface.Create;
  try
    Surface.SetSize(FDestBmp.Width, FDestBmp.Height);
    if not DecryptBmp(FHandle, Surface.ScanLine[Surface.Height - 1], ASourceData, ASourceSize) then
      raise EDecryptBmpError.Create('Bitmap cannot be decrypted');
    FDestBmp.Assign(Surface);
  finally
    Surface.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If the caller wants to show a message alerting the user to a successful decryption, then the caller should do that itself (I appreciate you may have only included that line for debugging purposes however - it was difficult to tell).